# Whats wrong with this bcp utility?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005, t-sql, bcp

I am trying to export data into into a text file using bcp utility? I could n't figure out what i am doing wrong here:-

```
Declare @Cmd nvarchar(1000)
Declare @Query nvarchar(1000)
Declare @Path nvarchar(500)
Declare @ServerName nvarchar(500)
Declare @UserName nvarchar(50)
Declare @Password nvarchar(50)
Declare @Delimiter char(1)

SET @Path = 'c:\abc.txt'
SET @ServerName = '10.10.10.10\instance1'
Set @UserName = 'sa'
Set @Password = '123456'
Set @Delimiter = '!'

SET @Query = 'SELECT [ID]
          , NULL
          ,[NAME]
          ,[STREET1] + '' '' + [STREET2] as [Address]
          ,[CITY] + '' '' + [PROVINCE] + '' '' + [POSTAL] as City
          ,[PHONE] 
          ,[FAX]
          ,''Title'' as [Title]
          ,[Country]
FROM [temp01]'
SET @Cmd = 'bcp "' + @Query + '" queryout "' +  @Path +
         '" -c -S' + @ServerName + ' -U' + @UserName + ' -P' + 
        @Password + ' -t' + @Delimiter + ''
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @Cmd
```

It is not writing any data into the file. In result box i am getting this output:-

usage: bcp {dbtable | query} {in | out | queryout | format} datafile
  [-m maxerrors]            [-f formatfile]          [-e errfile]
  [-F firstrow]             [-L lastrow]             [-b batchsize]
  [-n native type]          [-c character type]      [-w wide character type]
  [-N keep non-text native] [-V file format version] [-q quoted identifier]
  [-C code page specifier]  [-t field terminator]    [-r row terminator]
  [-i inputfile]            [-o outfile]             [-a packetsize]
  [-S server name]          [-U username]            [-P password]
  [-T trusted connection]   [-v version]             [-R regional enable]
  [-k keep null values]     [-E keep identity values]
  [-h "load hints"]
NULL
[-h "load hints"] NULL

Please help.

Comment: @gbn: bcp "SELECT [ID], NULL,[NAME] ,[STREET1] + ' ' + [STREET2] as [Address]
       ,[CITY] + ' ' + [PROVINCE] + ' ' + [POSTAL] as City
       ,[PHONE] 
       ,[FAX]
       ,'TITLE' as [Title]
       ,[Country]
     FROM [temp01]" queryout "c:\abc.txt" -c -S10.10.10.10\instance1 -Usa -P123456 -t!

Answer (score 10):

This question is pretty old, but I've had the same issue. You need the entire command to reside on a single line. Take out any line breaks in @Query and @Cmd.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a space after your -S switch.  Also, in general, when debugging something complex reduce the complexity until you can identify where the problem is.  In this case, you can remove each switch one at a time (or remove all of them to start) to determine whether or not that's causing the problem.

Comment: No, unfortunately its not a space after -S Switch?

Comment: try changing your code to 
SET @Cmd = 'bcp "' + @Query + '" queryout "' +  @Path 
just for testing.  Also, try simplifying your query like 
SET @Query = 'SELECT [ID] FROM [temp01]'

Answer (score 1):

SET @Cmd = 'bcp "' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(,CHAR(9),CHAR(32)),CHAR(13),CHAR(32)),CHAR(10),'')@Query + '" queryout "' +  @Path +
         '" -c -S' + @ServerName + ' -U' + @UserName + ' -P' + 
        @Password + ' -t' + @Delimiter + ''

Answer (score 0):

You do have to give a database. you only defined the instance an a table but no database. try change your select-statemen like : ...from [yourDB].[temp01]...

Answer (score -1):

I found the Same Issue While trying in my Database,
Hence I concluded that 
You are using

```
SET @Query = 'SELECT [ID]
           , NULL
           ,[NAME]
           ,[STREET1] + '' '' + [STREET2] as [Address]
           ,[CITY] + '' '' + [PROVINCE] + '' '' + [POSTAL] as City
           ,[PHONE] 
           ,[FAX]
           ,''Title'' as [Title]
           ,[Country] FROM [temp01]'
```

If U use

```
SET @Query = 'SELECT [ID], NULL ,[NAME],[STREET1] + '' '' + [STREET2] as [Address],[CITY] + '' '' + [PROVINCE] + '' '' + [POSTAL] as City,[PHONE],[FAX],''Title'' as [Title],[Country] FROM [temp01]'
```

Will Work Fine Without any new line in the Query
Just because it  is not accepting the Space in between.

Thanks